# How to create multiple variables efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, encode

I have a survey in a DataFrame. I want to translate some object variables and encode them for analysis. Each question is a column of this dataframe. Some respondents chose multiple categories for some questions.
For example:

```
df1["question_8"].value_counts()
```

has as output

```
Rouge                                        19
Rouge, Rosé, Blanc                           17
Rouge, Rosé, Blanc, Effervescent             13
Rouge, Blanc                                  8
Blanc                                         7
Rouge, Rosé                                   7
Rouge, Rosé, Blanc, Effervescent, Dessert     6
Rosé                                          2
Rouge, Rosé, Effervescent                     2
Rosé, Blanc                                   1
Rouge, Blanc, Fortifié                        1
Rouge, Blanc, Effervescent                    1
Fortifié                                      1
Rouge, Rosé, Blanc, Dessert                   1
Blanc, Dessert                                1
Effervescent                                  1
```

I separate every word like this, now I have 4 variables:

```
    new=df1["question_8"].str.split(",",n=4,expand=True)
    df1["question_8_a"]=new[0]
    df1["question_8_b"]=new[1]
    df1["question_8_c"]=new[2]
    df1["question_8_d"]=new[3]
```

For the translation I  used .replace()

```
df1["question_8_a"]=df1["question_8_a"].replace(df1.question_8_a.unique().tolist(),['Red','nan','Fortified','White','Rose','Sparkling'])
df1["question_8_b"]=df1["question_8_b"].replace(df1.question_8_b.unique().tolist(),['Rose','none','White','nan','Dessert'])
df1["question_8_c"]=df1["question_8_c"].replace(df1.question_8_c.unique().tolist(),['Sparkling','nonee','White','Fortified','nan'])
df1["question_8_d"]=df1["question_8_d"].replace(df1.question_8_d.unique().tolist(),['None','nan','Sparkling','Dessert'])
```

To encode, I first create a binary column for every option in the 4 variables I previously created:

```
df1["question_8_a_red"]=np.where(df1["question_8_a"].str.contains("Red"),1,0)
df1["question_8_a_rose"]=np.where(df1["question_8_a"].str.contains("Rose"),1,0)
df1["question_8_a_white"]=np.where(df1["question_8_a"].str.contains("white"),1,0)
df1["question_8_a_sparkl"]=np.where(df1["question_8_a"].str.contains("Sparkling"),1,0)
df1["question_8_a_Fortified"]=np.where(df1["question_8_a"].str.contains("Fortified"),1,0)

df1["question_8_b_rose"]=np.where(df1["question_8_b"].str.contains("Rose"),1,0)
df1["question_8_b_white"]=np.where(df1["question_8_b"].str.contains("white"),1,0)
df1["question_8_b_dessert"]=np.where(df1["question_8_b"].str.contains("Dessert"),1,0)

df1["question_8_c_white"]=np.where(df1["question_8_c"].str.contains("white"),1,0)
df1["question_8_c_sparkl"]=np.where(df1["question_8_c"].str.contains("Sparkling"),1,0)
df1["question_8_c_Fortified"]=np.where(df1["question_8_c"].str.contains("Fortified"),1,0)

df1["question_8_d_sparkl"]=np.where(df1["question_8_d"].str.contains("Sparkling"),1,0)
df1["question_8_d_dessert"]=np.where(df1["question_8_d"].str.contains("Dessert"),1,0)
```

And finally, to create the dummy variable for each answer I summed :

```
df1["question_8_red"]=df1["question_8_a_red"]
df1["question_8_rose"]=df1["question_8_a_rose"]+df1["question_8_b_rose"]
df1["question_8_white"]=df1["question_8_a_white"]+df1["question_8_b_white"]+df1["question_8_c_white"]
df1["question_8_sparkling"]=df1["question_8_a_sparkl"]+df1["question_8_c_sparkl"]+df1["question_8_d_sparkl"]
df1["question_8_dessert"]=df1["question_8_b_dessert"]+df1["question_8_d_dessert"]
df1["question_8_fortified"]=df1["question_8_a_Fortified"]+df1["question_8_c_Fortified"]
```

I have a dummy variable for each answer of question 8, finally! But, I am sure I can do this in a simpler way with a for loop or creating a function, I had tried to create something like that but I cannot! I finally ended up doing it "manually" .If someone could help me find a way to make this easier, that would be great.

Comment: Try looping through a dictionary of strings, like `{"red":"red", "sparkl":"sparkling", ...}` and doing what you're doing for each key or each value.